# How DICOM query(/retrieve) works using the REST-API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dicom

I am using MyDICOM.7.X.SDK.dll. Is there any way to query the DICOM.

Answer (score 1):

> It looks you are using incorrect terms. This is common in DICOM world; don't worry. I am attempting to answer based on what I understood. If this is not what you are looking for, let me know in comments and I will delete the answer.

I suspect you are looking for **Web Access to DICOM Persistent Objects (WADO)**. This is mostly used by HIS/RIS to load/display DICOM objects from PACS. This is loose HIS/RIS-PACS integration based on protocol.

Few PACS systems also use this to load lite version of their Image Viewer through browser. This is useful in some cases as mobile viewer or where zero installation is necessary.

Not exactly but yes; somehow, this is similar to CFind/CMove. Internal commands and responses work in similar way. DICOM Network protocol works on TCPIP. WADO works on HTTP.

Refer this link for sample: https://github.com/chafey/SimpleQIDOService